# Is it possible to choose a different shape instead of a circle for a HTML list without using an image?

Tags: html, list

Preferably looking for a triangle to replace the circle. I'd rather not use an image but I would if there was no other way.

Comment: Do you mean bullet lists?

Comment: Yes, for an unordered list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JSFiddle of triangle bullets](http://jsfiddle.net/2KZja/1/)

Hopefully this is what you mean?

CSS:

```
.ul1 {
    margin: 0.75em 0;
    padding: 0 1em;
    list-style: none;
}
.li1:before { 
    content: "";
    border-color: transparent #111;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0.35em 0 0.35em 0.45em;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    left: -1em;
    top: 0.9em;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yup. It's a bit of work though, if you want to use something other than circles or squares :)

See: http://alistapart.com/article/taminglists

The article I link to describes doing this by first stripping off the original markup:

```
ul.custom-list {
 list-style: none;
 margin-left: 0;
 padding-left: 1em;
 text-indent: -1em;
}
```

Then they add a custom bullet using the "before" pseudo-selector, and injecting content into that:

```
ul.custom-list li:before {
 content: "\0BB \020";
}
```

In this case, they're using it to include the "double chevron" symbol. You can look up the symbol code for whatever you want to inject.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use

```
list-style
```

style property for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple (and painless) solution for a triangle in your unordered list, then you could use this method. I simply wrote a fiddle where the CSS gives you a UL list with each item marked with a right-pointing triangle instead of a round bullet.

Is this what you were after?

http://jsfiddle.net/CU5Ry/

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>List Item 1</li>
    <li>List Item 2</li>
    <li>List Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
ul li:before {
    content: "\25BA \0020";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately there is no triangle available as a standard marker.
A full list of values for `list-style-type` can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-type.asp).

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Check this out. You can use CSS propriety as discribed here

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_ol_list-style-type&preval=cjk-ideographic